# Why naming convention of views files in rails are considered as action.html.erb only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why naming convention of views files in rails are considered as action.html.erb only ( instead of action.erb.html ) ?

What will happen if we write views files as action.erb.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen if we write views files as `action.erb.html`?

The first thing that will happen is that the Ruby syntax highlighting in your editor will stop working as the file extension is now `.html` instead of `.erb`. On almost every file system in use the file extension is the rightmost part of the file name.

The second thing that will happen is that Rails will no longer be able to lookup the template and even if it could it would no longer process it through ERB as it no longer has the `.erb` file extension.

`.html` is just a segment of the file name that lets the rails template resolver distinguish between templates for different formats when looking up a template for a given request format. Its not really technically part of the extension. For example:

```
show.html          #  just HTML - no processing
show.html.erb      #  a HTML ERB template
show.html.slim     #  a HTML Slim template
show.html.haml     #  a HTML Haml template

show.xml.erb       #  a XML ERB template
show.xml.slim      #  a XML Slim template
show.xml.haml      #  a XML Haml template

show.json.erb      #  a JSON ERB template
show.json.jbuilder #  a JSON jBuilder template
```

**TRDL;** changing the file extension is a dumb idea. Especially when you consider that Rails actually supports multiple template engines such as jbuilder, Slim and Haml in addition to ERB.